# Pay with Paypal account on Wordpress Gravity Forms with Paypal add on

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn, gravity-forms-plugin

We currently have Gravity Forms with the Paypal add on processing subscription payments on a Wordpress website. Gravity Forms submits all credit card information to Paypal and we have Paypal IPN listeners that update user accounts on Wordpress with the correct subscription details. (I.e. When a payment completes, we set the Wordpress user account to 'Paying Subscriber')

My question is this: how can we also allow users to check out with a Paypal account? For example, add a Pay with Paypal button that redirects to the Paypal site but still uses the same IPN listeners on Wordpress to update user accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you custom built something using the [Instant Payment Notification Script](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/), that might be your only other option. You could create PayPal subscription buttons, but they wont report back to your site with the IPN's.